# Frame breaks strange in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

The presentation I create  there are some ilustration. I need them together, so I use allowframebreaks. The first three frame is okay, but the fourth isn't broken to separate frame, but continues on the third (and isn't visible). I can't found any explanation in the manual, and don't understood it. Maybe there is something unnoticed error?

```
\documentclass[xetex]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Műveletek vektorokkal}
    \note{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Két vektor összege (3 perc)
            \item Két vektor különbsége (3 perc)
            \item Vektor szorzása skalárral (2 perc)
            \item Feladatmegoldás: vektorok koordinátarendszerben, műveletek (5 perc)
            \item Lineáris kombináció (4 perc)
            \item Vektorok felbontása (1 perc)
            \item Példák (2 perc)
        \end{itemize}
    }
    \begin{alertblock}
        {Definíció}
        Két vektor összegét az ábra alapján határozzuk meg:
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \tkzInit
                \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
                \tkzDefPoint(1,3){B}
                \tkzDefPoint(4,1){C}
                \tkzDefPoint(5,4){D}
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=blue](A,B)
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=blue](A,C)
                \tkzDrawSegment[dashed,color=lightgray](B,D)
                \tkzDrawSegment[dashed,color=lightgray](C,D)
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=green](A,D)
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{alertblock}
    \begin{alertblock}
        {Definíció}
        Két vektor különbségét az ábra alapján határozzuk meg:
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \tkzInit
                \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
                \tkzDefPoint(1,3){B}
                \tkzDefPoint(4,1){C}
                \tkzDefPoint(5,4){D}
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=blue](A,B)
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=blue](A,C)
                \tkzDrawSegment[dashed,color=lightgray](B,D)
                \tkzDrawSegment[dashed,color=lightgray](C,D)
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=green](B,C)
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{alertblock}
    \begin{alertblock}
        {Definíció}
        Egy vektor számszorosát úgy kapjuk meg, hogy a vektor irányát megtartjuk, abszolútértékét pedig megszorozzuk a vektor tényezőjével:
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5447]
                \tkzInit
                \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
                \tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
                \tkzDefPoint(6,9){A1}
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=blue](O,A)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,A){$\vec{v}$}
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=green](O,A1)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,A1){$3\cdot\vec{v}$}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{alertblock}
%Here begins the fourth frame...
    \begin{alertblock}
        {Definíció}
        Két vektor \alert{lineáris kombinációjának} nevezzük a számszorosaik összegét.
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4082]
                \tkzInit
                \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
                \tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
                \tkzDefPoint(4,1){B}
                \tkzDefPoint(4,6){A1}
                \tkzDefPoint(12,3){B1}
                \tkzDefPoint(16,9){C}
                \tkzDrawSegment[color=green,->](O,A1)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,A1){$1\cdot\vec{a}$}
                \tkzDrawSegment[color=green,->](O,B1)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,B1){$3\cdot\vec{b}$}
                \tkzDrawSegment[color=blue,->](O,A)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,A){$\vec{a}$}
                \tkzDrawSegment[color=green,->](O,B)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,B){$\vec{b}$}
                \tkzDrawSegment[color=red,->](O,C)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,C){$2\cdot\vec{a}+3\cdot\vec{b}$}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{alertblock}
    \begin{block}
        {Tétel}
        A síkon minden vektor felírható két kiválasztott, nem párhuzamos vektor lineáris kombinációjaként.
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem is caused by `\usetheme{metropolis}`. You might submit an issue to their github. https://github.com/matze/mtheme/issues

Comment: Ok, thanks! Sad, because all my foils made with this theme because very simple and fits with my school's colors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround. Don't put the `tikzpicture` inside the `alertblock`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Műveletek vektorokkal}
    \note{
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Két vektor összege (3 perc)
            \item Két vektor különbsége (3 perc)
            \item Vektor szorzása skalárral (2 perc)
            \item Feladatmegoldás: vektorok koordinátarendszerben, műveletek (5 perc)
            \item Lineáris kombináció (4 perc)
            \item Vektorok felbontása (1 perc)
            \item Példák (2 perc)
        \end{itemize}
    }
\begin{alertblock}{Definíció}
Két vektor összegét az ábra alapján határozzuk meg:
\end{alertblock}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \tkzInit
                \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
                \tkzDefPoint(1,3){B}
                \tkzDefPoint(4,1){C}
                \tkzDefPoint(5,4){D}
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=blue](A,B)
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=blue](A,C)
                \tkzDrawSegment[dashed,color=lightgray](B,D)
                \tkzDrawSegment[dashed,color=lightgray](C,D)
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=green](A,D)
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
\begin{alertblock}{Definíció}
Két vektor különbségét az ábra alapján határozzuk meg:
\end{alertblock}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \tkzInit
                \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
                \tkzDefPoint(1,3){B}
                \tkzDefPoint(4,1){C}
                \tkzDefPoint(5,4){D}
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=blue](A,B)
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=blue](A,C)
                \tkzDrawSegment[dashed,color=lightgray](B,D)
                \tkzDrawSegment[dashed,color=lightgray](C,D)
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=green](B,C)
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
\begin{alertblock}{Definíció}
Egy vektor számszorosát úgy kapjuk meg, hogy a vektor irányát megtartjuk, abszolútértékét pedig megszorozzuk a vektor tényezőjével:
\end{alertblock}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
                \tkzInit
                \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
                \tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
                \tkzDefPoint(6,9){A1}
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=blue](O,A)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,A){$\vec{v}$}
                \tkzDrawSegment[->,color=green](O,A1)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,A1){$3\cdot\vec{v}$}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
\begin{alertblock}{Definíció}
Két vektor \alert{lineáris kombinációjának} nevezzük a számszorosaik összegét.
\end{alertblock}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.35]
                \tkzInit
                \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
                \tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
                \tkzDefPoint(4,1){B}
                \tkzDefPoint(4,6){A1}
                \tkzDefPoint(12,3){B1}
                \tkzDefPoint(16,9){C}
                \tkzDrawSegment[color=green,->](O,A1)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,A1){$1\cdot\vec{a}$}
                \tkzDrawSegment[color=green,->](O,B1)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,B1){$3\cdot\vec{b}$}
                \tkzDrawSegment[color=blue,->](O,A)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,A){$\vec{a}$}
                \tkzDrawSegment[color=green,->](O,B)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,B){$\vec{b}$}
                \tkzDrawSegment[color=red,->](O,C)
                \tkzLabelSegment(O,C){$2\cdot\vec{a}+3\cdot\vec{b}$}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
\begin{block}{Tétel}
A síkon minden vektor felírható két kiválasztott, nem párhuzamos vektor lineáris kombinációjaként.
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image][image]